# SMB mounting from OSX

Tags: linux, windows, macos, command-line

Im trying to `mount smb` shares via OSX commandline. Ive tried various variations Ive seen online such as ;

```
mount -t smb //domain;user:pass@server/share /local/mountdir

mount_smbfs //domain;user:pass@server/share /local/mountdir
```

any various other combinations. I cant seem to get this to work at all. Can anyone suggest a command and the relevant syntax?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/344459/how-to-mount-samba-on-mac-osx-from-terminal

Comment: I have tried those already and they dont work (as in my question body) :(. Ill try them again

Comment: Nope still dont work. I just get usage info returned if I tried mount_smbfs with the syntax above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more trying, mixing up the syntax I worked out the correct syntax.

```
mount_smbfs //'domain;user:pass'@server/share /local/mountdir
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the quotes had to be like this (double or single quotes both worked):

```
mount_smbfs "//DOMAIN;user:pwd@host/share" ~/share
```